# I can't install programs in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I had to reinstall Ubuntu 10.10.

Now i can not install programs (flash, chromium...)

The computer shows this message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
```

Comment: @Juanjo the version of Ubuntu you are using is simply too old. The best thing for you to do is copy all your data to an external drive, then reinstall version 12.04 or 12.10.

Comment: @EliahKagan - looks like a correct dupe - dupe shows how to install EoL applications.

Comment: @fossfreedom You're quite right! Sorry, folks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.10(Maverick Meerkat) had reached end of life on April 10 2012. Its repositories is no longer maintained, as you can see at this [link](http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/). You have to install a currently supported Ubuntu version, preferably 12.04 LTS or 12.10.